# Power Query: erase row above on certain conditions "_"

Tags: indexing, count, powerbi, row, powerquery

I have the following:

```
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|    
  |       ID            |   Geography      |       Count      |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |    AB0000           |      ItalyZ      |      435         |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |    ZB4041           |      ItalyB      |       5435       |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |    BC0000           |      UKY         |        543       |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |    BC0000_1         |      UKM         |        543       |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |    BC0000_2         |      UKM         |     545543       |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |    CC0000           |      UKY         |      54433       |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |    CC0000_1         |      UKM         |      5543        |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |    CC0000_2         |      UKM         |      456543      |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I would like to get the following (without damaging other columns, such as the second column):

```
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|    
  |       ID            |   Geography      |       Count      |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |    AB0000           |      ItalyZ      |      435         |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |    ZB4041           |      ItalyB      |       5435       |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |    BC0000_1         |      UKM         |        543       |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |    BC0000_2         |      UKM         |     545543       |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |    CC0000_1         |      UKM         |      5543        |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
  |    CC0000_2         |      UKM         |      456543      |
  |---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

So whenever I have an ID with "_" in the end, I would like to suppress the row above.

**However there can be several "_" each followed by a number.**

Do you know how I could do that?

I tried in various unsuccessfully, from grouping, to splitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add column... index column...

Add column ... custom column with formula

```
= try Text.Contains(#"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[ID],[ID]&"_") otherwise false
```

that checks for a the next row having the same ID appended with a _ afterwards

Filter =False to take out the extra rows

Remove extra columns

Sample code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each try Text.Contains(#"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[ID],[ID]&"_") otherwise false),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] = false)),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index", "Custom"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Yes, this what I meant. Wherever there is a"_" I want to erase the row above.

Comment: OK! I tried it! It works! But I do not know why the very last line is 0? I have "True" and "falses" as well as a "0" at the very end. Why is that?

Comment: Because on the bottom row you cant find the next row down, that creates an error, and the Try...Otherwise... converts the error to a zero

Comment: But I realize that there is an issue. The only one that I want to supress is the row "above" the "_". And keep all the other "_" below. But in this case this supress not only the first row but all the other "_" below as well....

Comment: Ok...I am sorry. I see that my question is badly formulated because to ambiguous. I am going to change it. I edited the questions. So basically, suppressing the row each time the first round of "_" appears. I am sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Thank you ...I do not understand it "(#"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[ID],[ID]&"_")" this is a bit frustrating. I also sadly cannot accept this answer again because I accepted the previous one.

Comment: it takes the [ID] field of the current row+1  **#"Added Index"{[Index]+1}[ID]** and searches for the [ID] from the current row with a _ appended to the end  **[ID]&"_"**